# Shared library core dumping

Tags: c++, linux, g++, shared-libraries

Just to keep things simple for the purposes of discussion I'm going to use single letter identifiers to describe this situation.

I have a static library "A" that is being used in a shared library "B" which is being used in an application "C".

If I build all three on my main server, the test application runs without error.  However, if I copy "B" to another computer and build "C" on that machine I get a core dump on execution.  I've tried this with two other computers with the same result.  However, if I build "A" and "B" on one of those other computers then I can build and execute "C" on any of the computers without error (this includes the server that was originally used to build "A" and "B").

I'd normally suspect some kind of incompatibility in the OS or version mismatch in g++.  However, I've checked and the versions are the same on all machines involved.

The OS version is: 4.4.0-31-generic #50-Ubuntu x86_64 GNU/Linux
The g++ version is: g++ (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.1) 5.4.0 20160609

I've also checked the dependencies on "B" with ldd and they are identical no matter where "B" is built.

I'm at a total and complete loss for what might be causing this.  Suggestions greatly appreciated!

Comment: have you tried debugging the core dump?

Comment: Yes, it is blowing up inside "A" (the static library).  It has never had an issue where it is blowing up.  The specific error is an array out of bounds reference.

Comment: what about debugging the process before it core dumps - i.e. run in gdb

Comment: I could do that but I think that'd be focusing on the wrong thing.  The problem is I can build it and have it run exception free in one environment and then take it to another identical environment and have it crash.

Comment: If it's crashing, you have an error in your program that you need to debug. The fact that it doesn't crash on some environments is just luck.

Comment: You did not state where the "A" that crashed was built.